# Iterating through graph labels

Tags: python, mongodb, matplotlib

I am plotting a graph with several lines on it, and would like to assign to each line a particular label that will be shown in the legend.

This gives the same label to each line:

```
import pylab as P
connection = pymongo.Connection("mongodb://localhost", safe=True)
db = connection.stuff
data = stuff.collection

for i in data.find():
    a=[]
    for element in i["counts"]:
        a.append(element["total"])
    P.plot(a, label="first line")
    P.legend()

P.show()
```

I have a lot of data, my documents are structured in this way :

```
{name:..., data:..., counts:[{total:...,...},{total:...,...}]}
```

How can I assign a different label to each line within that snippet of code?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get your attribute from your data, you could do something of this style:

```
for i in data.find():
    a=[]
    somename = i["name"][??]        #maybe you can extract your label from here ?
    for element in i["counts"]:
        a.append(element["total"])
    P.plot(a, label=somename)       # and use it here
P.legend()
P.show()
```

Also, you should call `legend()` only once after all plots are finished.

Although not related with your question, note you can also build your list in this way:

```
for i in data.find():
    a = [element['total'] for element in i['counts']]
    P.plot(a, label=somename)
P.legend()
P.show()
```